# paste email to input and validation right away.

Tags: jquery

```
function checkEmail(){
  // Set variable
  var email_target = $("#signUpMenu-emailInput");
  var email_value = email_target.val();
  var email_errorspan = $("#email-errorResult");
  var emailpass_boolean;

  if(email_value === ""){
    // Email empty
    email_errorspan.html("Please enter your email.");
    email_errorspan.css("color", "red");
    email_target.css("border-color", "red");
  }else if(email_value > 0){
        email_errorspan.html("pass.");
    email_errorspan.css("color", "red");
    email_target.css("border-color", "red");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        // SINGUP EMAIL INPUT
    $("#signUpMenu-emailInput").bind({
      keyup : function(){
        checkEmail();
      },
      paste : function(){
        checkEmail();
      }
    });
});
```

my intention is do validation went user copy past on the input and it will validation it right away , but somehow if i paste , it ask me to enter your email the email should be ok , it should text out pass.

see my DEMO you will understand more.

How did i make my input check and validation after paste ?
[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/jL0hvfvu/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Your validation is wrong, you're checking for a numeric value inside the field by doing

```
if(email_value > 0)
```

Change it to

```
if(email_value.length > 0)
```

Comment: is still the same , i dont know why

Comment: do `console.log(email_value)` and check the value

Answer (score 0):

Check out Email Extractor tool from [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/email-extractor-tool/), and find out how it is implemented in view source.